# Unique Forms for the Formula $f(x)=\sqrt[a]{100}^{a-1}*\sqrt[a]{x}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory, complex-numbers

I'm a student teacher and I grade on a curve that one of my professors used in a logic class. His original formula was $f(x)=10\sqrt{x}$ where $x$ represents the original grade before the curve. For instance, if you took an 100 question test and got an $81\%$: $$f(x)=10\sqrt{81}=10*9=90,$$ so your final grade would be a $90\%$.

Recently, I generalised the formula for fun and figured out that any severity of curve can be achieved by replacing $a$ in the formula $$f(x)=\sqrt[a]{100}^{a-1}*\sqrt[a]{x}.$$ I also figured out that as $a$ gets bigger, the necessary grade to pass gets smaller and vice versa.

This morning, I was thinking about $\phi$ (the Golden Ratio) and its properties and I put them to the test on my formula rendering it as $$f(x)=\sqrt[\phi^2]{100}*\sqrt[\phi]{x}.$$

To my knowledge, $\phi$ is the only value for which $n-1=\frac{1}{n}$, but I was wondering if there were any other numbers which, when replaced for $a$ would render a formula not in the form $$f(x)=\sqrt[a]{100}^{a-1}*\sqrt[a]{x}.$$

Note: I haven't played around with Complex Numbers yet, but I'd be interested if any of those work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for instances where $(a-1)/a=1/a^m$, where $m$ is an integer. In the real numbers, you are searching for numbers that satisfy $a-1=a^{-n}$, where $n$ is an integer. Such a family of numbers exist and are associated with Fibonacci-Narayana sequences, i.e., $f_k=f_{k-1}+f_{k-1-n};\ f_{k\le n-1}=1$. There are an infinite number of these; the well known ones are the golden ratio $\varphi$, $n=1$, as you have observed, the supergolden ratio $\psi$, $n=2$, and the plastic number $p$, $n=4$. All of these numbers are limiting values of successive ratio of their sequences.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'm something of an amateur mathematician (that is, I don't study it or use it frequently; it's more of a passive interest for me). Do you have any pointers on where I could learn more about the Fibonacci-Narayana sequences?

Comment: @CurtisSheppard  There is a wonderful resource online called the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, or OEIS (https://oeis.org/) where you can look that up. The moniker Fibonacci-Narayana is my own, so search for each name individually. P.S. You can give me a vote for a satisfactory answer as well as an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

This boils down to an open ended question on representing a function in an aesthetically pleasing way.  You can find solutions for $a$ to $(a-1)/a=k$ for any integer $k$ so that you can write the formula with 100 raised to the integer power $k$, for instance.

Comment: That's an interesting way of thinking about the problem. Could $k$ also be a complex number or would that only be a way of getting real numbers? I don't see a reason why it would be limited to the reals, but as I said in response to the other answer, I'm don't study/use maths seriously as it's more of a passive interest of mine.

Comment: Sure, in general k can be whatever you desire it to be.  Although complex k would generally produce a complex result for the formula, which seems less applicable to the grading application.

Comment: Ah, that's true. Unless I found a way that $f(x)=\sqrt[\mathbb{C}]{100}^{\mathbb{C}-1}*\sqrt[\mathbb{C}]{x}$ such that most values of $f(x)$ are $\mathbb{R}$. I don't know how to go about finding it off the top of my head, but if $\mathbb{C}=a+bi$ where $b\neq0$ could be interesting to find.

Comment: Yep, you can use Euler's formula when dealing with complex exponentials: $e^{ix}=cos(x)+isin(x)$.  For other bases $r$, use the fact $r^{ix}=e^{i x ln (r)}.$  The famous Euler's identity shows how a complex exponential can give rise to a real result: $e^{i\pi}=-1$.